# Problem with Django class-based LogoutView in Django 5.0

Tags: django, post, get, django-class-based-views, django.contrib.auth

I used Django class-based login and logout views by "django.contrib.auth.urls", login feature works correctly, but when logging out via the link "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout" it returns an http 405 error page, saying "method not allowed (GET)".
I found out this logout feature was available in django 4.0 but in django 5.0 it's removed.

> *Support for logging out via GET requests in the django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView and django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login() is removed.* -[djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0)

How can I fix it?

I think I should somehow make it use POST request instead GET request when loging out but don't know how.

Comment: You use a POST request. Can you share the template where you have a log out button?

Comment: {% if  user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log In</a>

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77690729/django-built-in-logout-view-method-not-allowed-get-users-logout#:~:text=company%20blog-,Django%20built%20in%20Logout%20view%20%60Method%20Not%20Allowed,GET)%3A%20%2Fusers%2Flogout%2F%60&text=Since%20Django%2D5%2C%20you%20need,violation%20of%20the%20HTTP%20protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the request method used, my initial template used GET method:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} 
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log In</a>
```

but by editing the template to this:

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

path(
"logout/",
auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
http_method_names=["post", "get", "options"]
),