# Django built in Logout view `Method Not Allowed (GET): /users/logout/`

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-authentication

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /users/logout/
Method Not Allowed: /users/logout/
[10/Dec/2023 12:46:21] "GET /users/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

This is happening when I went to url http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/logout/

`urls.py:`

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...other urls...
    path('users/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

I am expecting user to logout

Comment: Since Django-5, you need to do this through a POST request, since it has side-effects. The fact that it worked with a GET request was (likely) a violation of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [django-5](/questions/tagged/django-5), you need to do this through a **POST request**, since it has side-effects. The fact that it worked with a GET request was (likely) a violation of the HTTP protocol: it made it possible for certain scripts to log out users, without the user wanting to. So a POST request also protects against [*cross-site request forgery (CSRF)* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

So in the template, work with a mini-form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Is there a way to do that without a <button> ?

Comment: @Gildas why do you need to do logout without a button?

Comment: @SuhailPIXL: the action here is to visit a url that do the logout. Now, from what I understand, we have to submit a form using post, which is done by clicking the <button> in this example. My question is if there is a way to do that using a normal <a></a> link. sorry if this is a noob question ;)

Comment: `<form id="frm_logout" method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a  href="javascript:$('#frm_logout').submit();" >logout</a>
</form>`

Comment: @Gildas: if it is just a matter of styling you can use css to style a button like a link.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue but i solve this with following code

```
<form id="frm_logout" method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">     {% csrf_token %}     <a  href="javascript:$('#frm_logout').submit();" class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700">logout</a> </form>
```

this line you write before ending the body tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```