# logout in drf api browser it shows HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I perform logout and login operations in **Djnago Rest Framework**. I logout using drf api browser it shows HTTP ERROR 405 my version is `Django==5.0.1`
when i decrease version `Django==3.2.10` it works perfect

Is there any solution in Django==5.0.1 to resolve this issue ?

[image: showing this page on logout]

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/9206

Since `django-5`, you need to do logout through a `POST` request. The fact that it worked with a GET request was (likely) a violation of the HTTP protocol: it made it possible for certain scripts to log out users, without the user wanting to. So a POST request also protects against cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

see [Django built in Logout view `Method Not Allowed (GET): /users/logout/`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77690729/22912974)